# Groupby In Pandas Dataframe with MultiIndexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

***PS: GroupBy with column as `name`***

I have tried creating DataFrame with MultiIndexing:

```
import pandas as pd

df = [ [ 'las_00', '6', '3', '3', 'a', '1.03', '1.11', '1.11' ],
       [ 'las_01', '6', '3', '3', 'b', '1.03', '1.11', '1.11' ],
       [ 'las_02', '6', '3', '3', 'c', '1.03', '1.11', '1.11' ],
       [ 'las_03', '6', '3', '3', 'a', '1.03', '1.11', '1.11' ],
       [ 'las_03', '6', '3', '3', 'b', '1.03', '1.11', '1.11' ]
    ]


new_df = pd.DataFrame( df , columns = [ 'name, name', 'transactionCount, totalCount', 'transactionCount, passCount', 'transactionCount, failCount', 'status, failPerc', 'status, mean',
                    'status, perc90', 'status, max' ] )


a = new_df.columns.str.split( ', ', expand=True ).values

new_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples( [ ( ' ', x[ 0 ] ) if pd.isnull( x[ 1 ] ) else x for x in a])
```

Resultant dataframe is:

```
     name               transactionCount                       status
     name       totalCount passCount failCount failPerc  mean perc90   max
0  las_00                6         3         3        a  1.03   1.11  1.11
1  las_01                6         3         3        b  1.03   1.11  1.11
2  las_02                6         3         3        c  1.03   1.11  1.11
3  las_03                6         3         3        a  1.03   1.11  1.11
4  las_03                6         3         3        b  1.03   1.11  1.11
```

**Now I want to use GroupBy with name** I tried using `level` but not getting how to use column `name`. Could anyone help with this!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
new_df.groupby(('name','name'))
```

Comment: Thanks It's working! Just needed any other alternative which can work for more such nesting.. So that I haven't to type ('name','name') as nesting may go long

Comment: Will the topmost column always be called `name`? Or will all the nesting be called `name`?

Comment: for columns `name` and `transactionCount` we have common index as `summary`

Comment: Try this: `df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_loc('name').argmax()]`

Comment: It's returning reqd field but I don't think It will help in groupby on whole dataframe. Previous soln was better

Comment: Well, I don't quite understand what you're looking for, then...

Comment: Yeah! thanks for t time.. Would prefer solution given in answer, it's working for the given scenario

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can groupby dataframe column slices:

```
new_df.groupby(new_df.columns[0])
```